# How solve IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type in ConvNet?

Tags: python, plot, 3d, conv-neural-network

I don't know how solve the error IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type in my ConvNet. First of all I created the array that contents DICOM images from a folder. The goal is display the 3D plot of this np.array called train_patient. Moreover 'patient = load_scan (path)', so the variable in which 'download' the path of the images.
I read many questions on this platform and applied answers to my code but the error remains. So here there is my code:

```
def resample(image, scan, new_spacing=[1,1,1]):
    # Determine current pixel spacing
    spacing = np.array([scan[0].SliceThickness] + list(scan[0].PixelSpacing), dtype=np.float32)

    resize_factor = spacing / new_spacing
    new_real_shape = image.shape * resize_factor
    new_shape = np.round(new_real_shape)
    real_resize_factor = new_shape / image.shape
    new_spacing = spacing / real_resize_factor
    
    image = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(image, real_resize_factor, mode='nearest')
    
    return image, new_spacing
```

Apply the above function:

```
pix_resampled, spacing = resample(train_patient, patient, [1,1,1])
print("Shape before resampling\t", train_patient.shape)
print("Shape after resampling\t", pix_resampled.shape)
```

It results:

```
Shape before resampling  (129, 512, 512)
Shape after resampling   (206, 400, 400)
```

Define the 3D plot function:

```
def plot_3d(image, threshold=-300):
    
    # Position the scan upright, 
    # so the head of the patient would be at the top facing the camera
    p = image.transpose(2,1,0)
    
    verts, faces = measure.marching_cubes_classic(p, threshold)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    # Fancy indexing: `verts[faces]` to generate a collection of triangles
    mesh = Poly3DCollection(verts[faces], alpha=0.70)
    face_color = [0.45, 0.45, 0.75]
    mesh.set_facecolor(face_color)
    ax.add_collection3d(mesh)

    ax.set_xlim(0, p.shape[0])
    ax.set_ylim(0, p.shape[1])
    ax.set_zlim(0, p.shape[2])

    plt.show()
```

```
def largest_label_volume(im, bg=-1):
    vals, counts = np.unique(im, return_counts=True)

    counts = counts[vals != bg]
    vals = vals[vals != bg]

    if len(counts) > 0: # &amp;gt;
        return vals[np.argmax(counts)]
    else:
        return None

def segment_lung_mask(image, fill_lung_structures=True):
    
    # not actually binary, but 1 and 2. 
    # 0 is treated as background, which we do not want
    binary_image = np.array(image > -320, dtype=np.int8)+1 # &amp;gt;
    labels = measure.label(binary_image)
    
    # Pick the pixel in the very corner to determine which label is air.
    #   Improvement: Pick multiple background labels from around the patient
    #   More resistant to "trays" on which the patient lays cutting the air 
    #   around the person in half
    background_label = labels[0,0,0]
    
    #Fill the air around the person
    binary_image[background_label == labels] = 2
    
    
    # Method of filling the lung structures (that is superior to something like 
    # morphological closing)
    if fill_lung_structures:
        # For every slice we determine the largest solid structure
        for i, axial_slice in enumerate(binary_image):
            axial_slice = axial_slice - 1
            labeling = measure.label(axial_slice)
            l_max = largest_label_volume(labeling, bg=0)
            
            if l_max is not None: #This slice contains some lung
                binary_image[i][labeling != l_max] = 1

    
    binary_image -= 1 #Make the image actual binary
    binary_image = 1-binary_image # Invert it, lungs are now 1
    
    # Remove other air pockets insided body
    labels = measure.label(binary_image, background=0)
    l_max = largest_label_volume(labels, bg=0)
    if l_max is not None: # There are air pockets
        binary_image[labels != l_max] = 0
 
    return binary_image
```

Apply the above functions:

```
segmented_lungs = segment_lung_mask(pix_resampled, False)
segmented_lungs_fill = segment_lung_mask(pix_resampled, True)
plot_3d(segmented_lungs, 0)
```

The code gives me:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-289-2e5dea6ade8b> in <module>()
      1 segmented_lungs = segment_lung_mask(pix_resampled, False)
      2 segmented_lungs_fill = segment_lung_mask(pix_resampled, True)
----> 3 plot_3d(segmented_lungs, 0)

1 frames
<ipython-input-287-c4ec00976999> in plot_3d(image, threshold)
      5     p = image.transpose(2,1,0)
      6 
----> 7     verts, faces = measure.marching_cubes_classic(p, threshold)
      8 
      9     fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/skimage/measure/_marching_cubes_classic.py in marching_cubes_classic(volume, level, spacing, gradient_direction)
    130 
    131     # Fancy indexing to define two vector arrays from triangle vertices
--> 132     faces = _correct_mesh_orientation(volume, verts[faces], faces, spacing,
    133                                       gradient_direction)
    134 

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Anyone know how this can be solved? Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace

Comment: @MichaelRuth i edited just now, adding more information. Need more?